# An adjective for "one who doesn't understand or appreciate the importance of something"

Tags: adjectives

There is an adjective in my mother tongue (Turkish), "kıymet bilmez"...

We use it to describe the people who don't understand or appreciate the good things, the good opportunities etc. which they have. They take everything for granted.

Is there some common adjective in English to describe such a man or woman...

Best regards...

Comment: Your text translates to ungrateful. You have to narrow down your requirements.

Comment: Consider "jaded" or "blasé". *feeling or showing a lack of interest and excitement for good things*

Comment: You've said it yourself - if they don't **appreciate** things they are [unappreciative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unappreciative) or [inappreciative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inappreciative).

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a noun for this: *ingrate*. It's now a little archaic, but you'll see it in writing pre-1900.

I don't think it's your meaning, but someone who "doesn't appreciate the good things they have" because they don't understand them or don't choose to value them is often called a *Philistine*.

You can use adjectives, of which *ungrateful* is the most obvious.

However, if you want a nice idiomatic turn of phrase, we have *to not know you're born* (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/not-know-one-is-born) which covers it admirably.
Sample usage:

> "I can't believe he said that about the NHS. Some people don't know they're born!"

*(point of context: the NHS is the British national health service, where you get fantastic health treatment for free, hence the example)*